# Farmer, Wolf, Goat and Cabbage Problem: full decision tree in C

Tags: c, backtracking

I put a backtracking algorithm around the Farmer, Wolf, Goat and Cabbage problem - to see if there are any *interesting* branches, besides the (two) 7-step solutions.

**WGC Problem**: A Farmer with a wolf, a goat and a giant cabbage has to cross a river on a tiny boat that can only carry **him plus one** of the three cargo loads. Problem is: the **Goat** starts eating the cabbage as soon as the Farmer is on the **other** side. The **Wolf** does the same to the goat. Can he ferry all 3 to the other side under these rules/constraints?

sakharov.net has a very nice description (calling it "Russian"). I read long ago the story's traces get lost in the Middle Ages. Cabbage (soup) and wolf (Peter and) being typical Russian things. Here's sakharov's version:

> This is an old and famous Russian puzzle. Try to carry Wolf, Goat and
> Cabbage across a river in a boat. You can take on the boat with you
> only one of them in each trip. If you leave Wolf and Goat on the same
> bank, Wolf will eat Goat. If you leave Goat and Cabbage on the same
> bank, Goat will eat Cabbage. Although, they will never eat one another
> while you stay with them. Make sure they all safely reach the other
> river bank.

Then you can realistically "play". Loading and unloading is separate from crossing, a nice way to distract the player a bit. You get a message when you make an "illegal" move.

> You can move a **person/animal/object** to the boat by clicking on its
> image.   Clicking on an image in the boat moves one back.
>
> To move the boat to another bank, press the '<<' or '>>' buttons.

**person/animal/object**: I had and have the same problem. I chose "Animals". It feels wrong now to turn "cabbage" into "salad". But the salad (to me) is as edible as a wolf is dangerous. Some use fox, hen and beans. Some sell their soul just to extend the problem and call it cannibals and missionaries.

---

I am thinking of adding an interactive version (called instead of `backtrack_fsgw()` from `main()`), giving the user (who has to play blindly) messages like:

"Can't take the Salad. Goat and wolf would be left together."

"There is no goat here"

"You just brought the wolf from that side"

"You are turning in circles. You were with the goat on that side 6 crossings ago"

---

On first view it seems a dilemma. Then you realize it *can* be solved (by taking the goat back at step 4). Then you realize: it can almost **not be not solved**: every choice is compulsory, except silly direct repetitions.

You have to look closely to find a way to prolong the procedure, by constantly rotating the 3 passengers. Instead of going back empty at the end to fetch the lone goat, you can take back the wolf or salad, whichever you did **not** carry last. (if you do choose the other, it is not the start of a cycle, but a (silly) direct repetition)

Here is the output. Farmer(=empty ferry), Salad, Goat and Wolf are 0, 1, 2 and 3 resp.

```
ALL CROSSED - Level= 7  2012302
ALL CROSSED - Level=13  2012312312302
ALL CROSSED - Level=19  2012312312312312302
ALL CROSSED - Level=25  2012312312312312312312302
ALL CROSSED - Level=31  2012312312312312312312312312302
MAXLEVEL reached - backtracking to escape cycle: ...12312312
ALL CROSSED - Level= 7  2032102
ALL CROSSED - Level=13  2032132132102
ALL CROSSED - Level=19  2032132132132132102
ALL CROSSED - Level=25  2032132132132132132132102
ALL CROSSED - Level=31  2032132132132132132132132132102
MAXLEVEL reached - backtracking to escape cycle: ...32132132
```

It goes on of course finding "solutions" if not stopped by a maxlevel. It is a kind of benign, non-branching cycle. WITH silly reps included, you get an enormous number of boring branches.

This is the filtered output lines (both kinds).

The full output displays the "state of the riversides". Here the lines 20-70 with the first solution.

```
...

[ 5 LEVEL]  cur:[-1] parent: 2
0: *.**
1: .*..
    --> new node:[3] and state: 
0: ..*.
1: **.*

[ 6 LEVEL]  cur:[-1] parent: 3
0: ..*.
1: **.*
    --> new node:[0] and state: 
0: *.*.
1: .*.*

[ 7 LEVEL]  cur:[-1] parent: 0
0: *.*.
1: .*.*
    --> new node:[2] and state: 
0: ....
1: ****

ALL CROSSED - Level= 7  2012302
[ 6 LEVEL]  cur:[0] parent: 3
0: ..*.
1: **.*
    --> new node:[1] and state: 
0: ***.
1: ...*

...
```

This quite sums up what the program does.

To my surprise I ended up with a 3D-array via `typedef`. With `int **sh` I had to use it like `(*sh)[fside]`. Plus other pointer-is-not-array related warnings and errors. Now it is:

```
 next_node(Shores_t sh, ...
 ...
     ferry(sh, anim, fside);                     
     if (is_unsafe(sh[fside]))
```

Questions:

I guess if you want arrays, this is one of many right ways to do it. Might even work with variable/runtime stack size.

Would a `struct shores` be more flexible for passing, for putting in an array and for accessing?

What to put inside that struct? I don't think `sh.goat` works if enum item `Goat` is integer `2`. Maybe the way to go if you use pure logic.

Or do I just *wrap* a `struct`around the existing typedef?

`struct shores { Shores_t sht };`

and then `sh->sht[Dest][Farmer]` ?

This is even worse than `(*sh)[Dest][Farmer]`.

Do I have to make an array of pointers? Like usual with dynamic 2D arrays?

Eight or even just four bits would be enough to hold a complete state. But I don't want it small and fast.

Any general ideas for this specific case ?

Any comments about the code below?

```
/*  Farmer, Wolf, Goat and Cabbage    
    River Crossing Problem/Puzzle/Dilemma

Here the cabbage is a salad - "fsgw" instead of FWGC (or FCGW).

The 'none' option (or 'Alone') was renamed 'Farmer' to use it better
(see all_on_side() and ferry()).  These four items (symbols) are numerically represented 
as 'Animals' (as living beings) via enum. 

The first Shores_t (both Sides_t of the river) looks like:
   { {1,1,1,1}, {0,0,0,0} }
This is a bit redundant, but robust/clear (see is_unsafe()). 
Alternative: only 4 bools e.g. "1010" as "FcGw"; the other side then is virtual/the inverse.              

By avoiding simple node/move repeats (ferry *directly* back what you just ferried),
there is only a 3-cycle pattern (rotating the items after 6 cycles) amd it can easily be broken. 
An alternative would be to check for *state* repetitions in the *whole* stack.  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* For different backtrack patterns (and for testing) the sequence can be changed */ 
enum {Farmer, Salad, Goat, Wolf, Animals}; 
//enum {Salad, Wolf, Goat, Farmer, Animals};
enum {Start, Dest, Sides};

typedef int     Side_t   [Animals];                   /* For real 2D array without 'int...[2][4]' everywhere */  
typedef Side_t  Shores_t [Sides];

int 
is_unsafe(Side_t b) {                                       /* b: where the farmer is NOT */
    return b[Goat] && ( b[Salad] || b[Wolf] );
}
int 
all_on_side(Side_t d) {                                     /* d: 'Dest' side to test for success */
    return d[Farmer] && d[Salad] && d[Goat] && d[Wolf]; 
}

/* Visualize a "shore[2][4]" (Two sides with four slots).  
A bit of Conway life, just as jumpy on small scale */
/* The enum determines which of f,s,g and w is 0,1,2 or 3  */
void
show_state(Shores_t sh) {
    for (int s = 0; s < Sides; s++) {
        printf("%d: ",  s);
        for (int i = 0; i < Animals; i++)
            printf(sh[s][i] ? "*" : ".");
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
/* Show chain of nodes up to level 'end', for solutions. One-based. */
void
show_nodes(int *n, int end) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= end; i++)
        printf("%d", n[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
/* Cross the river alone or with an 'anim' =
Check-out at 'from' and check-in at NOT-'from' */
void 
ferry(Shores_t sh, int anim, int from) {
    int to = !from; 
    sh[from][anim] = 0; 
    sh[to]  [anim] = 1;
    if (anim != Farmer) {           /* (or just repeat with same value) */
        sh[from][Farmer] = 0;      
        sh[to]  [Farmer] = 1;
    }
}
/* Returns next valid node, above current, and different from lower node (no direct repetition!). */ 
/* Or -1 if none left.  Also updates the state stack by reference 'Shores_t sh'. */
int 
next_node(Shores_t sh, Shores_t sh_0, int anim, int anim_0) {

    memcpy(sh, sh_0, sizeof(Shores_t));         /* Work on last state in new level on stack */
    const int fside = sh[1][Farmer];            /* Where is the farmer at all? (note [1], not [Dest], makes that trick (?) less confusing)*/

    while (++anim < Animals) {

        if (sh[fside][anim] && anim != anim_0) {

            ferry(sh, anim, fside);                     /* Test crossing... */
            if (is_unsafe(sh[fside]))
                ferry(sh, anim, !fside);                /* ...undone by ferry() in reverse */
            else 
                return anim;                            /* ...confirmed, done */
        }        
    }
    return -1;    
}

/* Backtrack FWGC (fsgw) using next_node() */
/* With indep. tests for max. level (cycle breaker) and for end state */
void
backtrack_fsgw(int *nodes, Shores_t *states, int MAX) {

    int LVL = 1;
    while (LVL > 0) {

        /* Display I: current level, old vars */
        printf("[%2.d LEVEL]  cur:[%d] parent: %d\n", LVL, nodes[LVL], nodes[LVL-1]);
        show_state(states[LVL-1]);

        nodes[LVL] = next_node(states[LVL], states[LVL-1], 
                                nodes[LVL],  nodes[LVL-1]);

        if (nodes[LVL] == -1)
            LVL--;

        else {
            /* Display II: after successful next_node() */
            printf("    --> new node:[%d] and state: \n",  nodes[LVL]);
            show_state(states[LVL]);
            putchar('\n');

            if (all_on_side(states[LVL][Dest])) {
                printf("ALL CROSSED - Level=%2.d  ", LVL);
                show_nodes(nodes, LVL);
                nodes[LVL--] = -1;
                continue;
            }
            if (LVL == MAX) {
                printf("MAXLEVEL reached - backtracking to escape cycle: ...");
                show_nodes(&nodes[LVL-8], 8);  /* not too much back, if MAX is very low...todo; but then again it only shows 123... or 321... */ 
                nodes[LVL--] = -1;             
                continue;
            }
            LVL++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

/* Stacks for (i.e. Arrays of) the nodes (moves) and the states (Shores_t, int[2][4]) */
int main(void) {

    /* Maximum level: 
       - 32 is enough to give solution pairs at levels 7, 13, 19, 25 and 31. Also enough crossings to give up.   
       -  8 is enough for the first/best solution pair */ 
    #define    MAXLEV 32            
    int      nodes [MAXLEV];
    Shores_t states[MAXLEV];

    int i;
    /* Unvisited nodes have -1 */
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLEV; i++) 
        nodes[i] = -1;

    /* Starting position of F,S,G,W on Shore Zero */    
    for (i = 0; i < Animals; i++) {
        states[0][Start][i] = 1;
        states[0][Dest] [i] = 0;
    }

    backtrack_fsgw(nodes, states, MAXLEV-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question would be greatly improved if you provided a simple text explanation of exactly what the "farmer-wolf-goat-cabbage" problem is.  It's familiar to some of us, but there are many variations, and so describing your *particular* version would be very helpful in reviewing the code.

Comment: Done. Now I prefer WGC as abbrev., but FSGW is my name for it in the code. The farmer is not really needed, only in the real-world story, and in most implementations including this one.

Comment: I understand, from your description, this requires three bits _per_ move?

Comment: I would say a move is two bits: one of W, G or C. The state (i.e. who is where after n moves) is 3 bits, *plus* where is the farmer; but that info is also in "number of moves modulo 2". I prefer to handle the farmer like a constantly moving object,

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a 3D-Array `a[][][]`

```
  int a[100][2][4];
  a[16][1][2] = 123456;
```

There are two ways to get the "reference" of `a[xx]`. With or without `typedef int Side_t[4]`. I even take `a[14]` and then `[1+4][2]`, because the first index is optional / array has no bounds.

```
  int (*p)[4] = a[14];
  /* Same as: */
  Side_t *p = a[14];
```

Now I can access all values relative to `a[14]`. For the second int in the fifth Side_t:

```
  printf("%d\n", p[5][2]);
```

And I get the number in `a[16][1][2]` skipping the four `...[0]` and `...[1]` entries in `a[14]` and `a[15]`.

### typedefs and function paramaters

By renaming `Sides_t` with `FSGW_t`, and duplicating it manually, you can also live without `Shores_t`. Here some ideas:

The array dimensions [2][4] could be more "officially" named:

```
enum {Farmer, Salad, Goat, Wolf, N_fsgw};
enum {Start, Dest, N_sides};
```

The array of 4 ints (i.e. F, S, G and W):

```
typedef int     FSGW_t   [N_fsgw];                   
//typedef FSGW_t  Shores_t [N_sides];
```

In `main()`:

```
FSGW_t   states[MAXLEV][2];
```

or even:

```
int      states[MAXLEV][2][4];    // 2 sides, 4 items FSGW
```

to see the whole thing.

The `backtrack_fsgw()` declaration is one of:

```
//backtrack_fsgw(int *nodes, Shores_t *states, int MAX) {
backtrack_fsgw(int *nodes, int states[][2][4], int MAX) {
backtrack_fsgw(int *nodes, int (*states)[2][4], int MAX) {
backtrack_fsgw(int nodes[], FSGW_t states[][2], int MAX) {
```

...

In `next_node()` there is a small problem without `sizeof(Shores_t)`.

```
int
next_node(FSGW_t sh[], void *sh_0, int anim, int anim_0) { 
    
    //memcpy(sh, sh_0, sizeof(FSGW_t)*2);         
    //memcpy(sh, sh_0, sizeof(FSGW_t[2]));        
    //memcpy(sh, sh_0, sizeof(int[2][4]));        
    memcpy(sh, sh_0, (void*)sh - sh_0);
```

I prefer the last version: it shows that we want only address and size of `sh_0`. `sizeof sh` does not work, because it is "only" a paramter array.

(But it needs no parens `(*sh)[...]`. It is a 3/4 array.

---

```
ferry(FSGW_t sh[2], int anim, int from) {
```

...or `sh[]` or `*sh`. The "2" is just to give information and reflects the limited range of 'from' and 'to' (0 and 1).

Then arriving back at the top:

```
int
is_unsafe(FSGW_t b) {                       /* b: where the farmer is NOT */
    return b[Goat] && ( b[Salad] || b[Wolf] )
```

I am not saying this `FSGW_t` single typedef version is better than the `Side_t/Shores_t` version. I just wanted to show how to handle multiple layers of arrays, even if there is no matching `typedef`

---

Array rule: "The first dimension is free" (the others are not). A first `[]` on the right is same as a `(*...)` around the identifer.

---

`next_node()` *could* be called more simple:

```
nodes[LVL] = next_node(nodes, states, LVL);
```

Then it has to define the working objects itself:

```
int
next_node(int nodes[], FSGW_t states[][2], int LVL) {

    int anim =   nodes[LVL];
    int anim_0 = nodes[LVL-1];
    FSGW_t *sh =   states[LVL];
    FSGW_t *sh_0 = states[LVL-1];

    memcpy(sh, sh_0, (sh-sh_0)*sizeof(FSGW_t));
```

Now `sh` and `sh_0` have difference of two (`FSGW_t`s), so in `memcpy()` the diff has to be multiplied.

All this only because `states[][][]` is not global...